# STM32 Cube IDE (True Studio) Connect under Reset

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubemx

I just tried out the new STM32 Cube IDE, which based on Atollic True Studio which based on Eclipse.

Looks good, Cube MX is integraded but the Debugger / ST-Link Intigration made problems by me.

If I flash a MCU for first time, it works pretty well. But on next time, the IDE says

"Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target."

I found out that the ST-Link V2 with my Hardware need a "Connect under Reset".

With the ST-Link Utility it works fine, but in Cube IDE I cant find that point to set up.

Here is the Config Form: [IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSaNb.png)

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem of the code, why the upload just works one time after full erase:

Cube IDE generate the HAL_MspInit() in ..stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c which contains:

```
__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_DISABLE();
```

With that all debug stuff will be disabled after first flash. 
With changing this line to:

```
__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_SWJ_NOJTAG();
```

The Debug mode works fine and several times in a row.

Comment: To solve the problem, go to CubeMX part and under SYS select SWD. Then you reserve these pins for SWD.

Answer (score 1):

With version up to `v1.0.1` it is not possible to connect under reset with STM32CubeIDE from GUI.

The reason(s) why you are having the issue could be:

- You are using low-power features where CPU is halted
- You are overwriting default alternate function setup for SWDIO and SWCLK pins (PA13 and PA14).

If you need to use *Connect under reset*, use *STM32CubeProgrammer* for flashing. Even better, try not to use sleep modes or do not overwrite flashing GPIOs for the test.

Comment: Thanks. In the Cube MX Config I dont use PA13/14, if I use low Power Stuff, its unaware, how can I check?

Generally, its a bug or a feature that's there are no "Connect under reset"?

Comment: @guenthernagel it is unimplemented feature, coming soon. Do you use ST board or your own one? Did you add some more code to the project? Do you use `__WFI` or `__WFE` instruction somewhere?

Comment: OK. Is there any workaround? Its possible to use external programmer/debugger directly out of the IDE?

Comment: @guenthernagel in normal conditions, programming should work and it works normally. So I would like to understand your hardware too.

Comment: Hmm. I use the EasyMX Pro v7 for ARM Development board from mikroelektronika - it have a onboard ST-LINK (They call it mikroProg) : https://www.mikroe.com/easymx-pro-stm32

If i erase the chip with ST-Link Utility by holding rst btn on board, I can write one time with Cube IDE

Comment: What I see right now is, If I erase the MCU with Utility and Debug it with IDE the first time, the code uploads but it dont run. Have to Stop Debugging then and make a reset, after that the code is running... Strage things...

Comment: Everything looks like you are using low-power features, or CPU clock is too slow (did you modify HCLK clock inside CubeMX?) Try to set maximal clock with internal RC oscillator.

Comment: Is the STLink gdbserver or openOCD documentation written in the dead language?

Comment: `With version up to v1.0.1 it is not possible to connect under reset with STM32CubeIDE` does everything have to be clickable? No strtup, no config files? no command line options? **It is possible to connect under reset**

Comment: @P__J__ technically you are right. I updated my answer ;)

Comment: @P__J__ which command I need for connect under Reset? I dont found the cmd line options.

Comment: @tilz0R, Clock is at 72MHz, with external OSC. How can I check the low-power settings? I tried it today with own hardware, similar to mikroE Stuff, still same problem.

Comment: @tilz0R found the problem by myself. Check out my answer on top.